# How to check the if a keyword is present in the SharePoint site description?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, jsom

One of the Projects I am working on, I have a requirement to read the SharePoint site description on page load and then based on the read description, i have to hide/show web parts.

So my site description for a site looks like: "Finance;Team site for Finance department."

Now using JSOM, I want to check if the site description contains the keyword Finance or not. Based on the value returned true or false, I have to do something. Below is the code I wrote which alerts me Site Description on page load but I am stuck at how to see if a site description contains the word Finance or not. Can someone please help me resolve this. Many thanks. Right now I am using .includes method to check if the description contains certain keyword or not. FYI, I am working with SharePoint online.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">   

$(document).ready(function() { 
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(Main, "sp.js");

    });
    function Main()
    { 
        GetSiteInfo();
    }

function GetSiteInfo()
    {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    this.oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
    clientContext.load(this.oWebsite);       

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
        );  
    }

    function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) 
    {   
        var Sitedes= this.oWebsite.get_description();        
        UpdateTiles(Sitedes);   
    alert(Sitedes);          
     }    

function failed(sender, args)
{
  alert("failed. Message:" + args.get_message());
} 

function UpdateTiles(des)
{
    var stagevalue = des.includes("Finance");

    switch(stagevalue){
    case 'true':
    $('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ5').hide();
    $('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ6').show();
    alert("Web part 1 hidden");
    break;

    case 'false':   
    $('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ5').show(); 
    $('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ6').hide();
    alert("Web part 2 hidden");
    break;

    case 'default':
    alert("something went wrong");
    break;
}   
}   
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.includes returns a Boolean. A true or false, not a string like 'true' or 'false'. Also, .includes is not supported in all browsers (like IE 11).

Consider changing the .includes line from:

```
var stagevalue = des.includes("Finance");
```

to:

```
var stagevalue = des.indexOf("Finance") >= 0;
```

For the test, try something like this:

```
if(stagevalue) {
  $('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ5').hide();
  $('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ6').show();
}
else
{
  $('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ5').show(); 
  $('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ6').hide();
}
```

Comment: Smith, exactly that is what I changed with reference to one of the blogs and it worked like a charm. Thanks so much for your response.